# Construct Eigen::Transform from Eigen::Translation

Tags: c++, eigen3

I have following code:

```
void mySetTransform(const Eigen::Affine3d& T);
...
mySetTransform(Eigen::Translation3d(1.0,2.0,3.0));
```

This doesn't compile, it can't convert the `Eigen::Translation3d` to `Eigen::Affine3d`. Following line causes the same error:

```
Eigen::Affine3d test = Eigen::Translation3d(r);
```

But this is fine:

```
Eigen::Affine3d test;
test = Eigen::Translation3d(r);
```

So, it looks like the the `=` operator works fine, but the constructor building `Eigen::Affine3d` with an `Eigen::Translation3d` is not defined.

The documentation has following [note](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Translation.html) for the `Translation` class:

> This class is not aimed to be used to store a translation
>   transformation, but rather to make easier the constructions and
>   updates of Transform objects.

Is there any way to declare the above function so that it can be called directly using any of the transformation objects like `Translation` declared in Eigen/Geomerty (without using a temporary variable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the constructor of Transform from a Translation is explicit. So you have to explicitly call it:

```
Translation3d t(1.0,2.0,3.0);
mySetTransform(Affine3f(t));
```

Let's consider the following two examples:

```
Affine3d test1(t);  // OK
Affine3d test2 = t; // NOT OK
```

Even though in both cases that's the constructor which is called (not operator=), only the first one will be OK for an explicit constructor. That's a standard C++ rule. Of course you can also do:

```
Affine3d test3 = Affine3d(t); // OK
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Calling the function on the beginning of my question works with `mySetTransform(Eigen::Affine3d(Eigen::Translation3d(1.0,2.0,3.0)));`. Having the constructor declared `explicit` makes the code slightly less readable in that example. I suppose there is a good reason to have an explicit ctor; I would appreciate if you can precise why it's explicit.

Comment: It's essentially to prevent unexpected overhead.